# Workspace Navigation in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, workspace

Folks

I have this weird thingy, I assigned shortcuts to move a window to a numbered workspace, eg: Ctrl+2 will move the window to the 2nd workspace, but it just doesn't work, it just doesn't move the window to the workspace

Any suggestions?!

**UPDATE:** If I right click the window and choose move window to workspace#, and I go to that workspace, the window is just not there, it's just like closed!! #weird!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you assign these keys?

I usually use CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+ UP LEFT RIGHT OR DOWN, depending on which workspace I wanna send it to.

Comment: From the Keyboard then Shortcuts then Navigation then assign each shortcut.

Comment: @0xab3d Try changing the "Move window one to workspace" Left, right,up and down instead. If I understand correct, you want to do it with the current window in focus? I will update my answer with this, if you can confirm this is what you are looking for

Comment: If I use the move to workspace on right shortcut it works perfectly, update, if i click the right click then move to workspace #2 it just closes the window, when I go to workspace 2 it's just not there!!!

Comment: When you click what? 
It should take the window to workspace 2 (right), but your focus will follow, so you end up at workspace 2 as well. Is this what you mean?

Comment: When I move it to workspace 2 the window for example (gnome-terminal) will just simply close!!

Comment: That sounds very weird - this is not happening to me.
Did you assign some other hotkeys recently which could be the reason for this behavior? Else I am sorry to say I have no idea why that is happening.

Comment: I've just re-installed Ubuntu 13.04, it doesn't crash now, but the shortcuts don't work, I've searched LaunchPad it seems a bug in Ubuntu.